# userform clear function seems not to be working

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform function to clear data. i only have 1 textbox which is named "InputBoxValue". I cant seem to clear it.

```
Private Sub ClearValueButton_Click()
    Me.Controls("InputBoxValue").Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What does *"I can't seem to clear it"* means? Do you get an error? Describe your problem.

Comment: in my userform when i click "Clear", the number in the userform didnt get cleared

Comment: Is the function called at all? Have you set a breakpoint to check?

Comment: Have you got `On Error Resume Next` in your code and spelt the control name incorrectly?

Comment: Do you have a `TextBox_Change` event that puts the value back in there when you clear the value (causing a change event to fire).

Comment: i just write Private Sub ClearValueButton_Click() InputBoxValue.Value = Null 
End Sub in the subroutine. But with that code, i still cant clear my textbox userform

Comment: In design view, double-click the button and see if the method above will get focus or a new one will be created. The button name could be different.

Comment: If you want 'clearing' a **text box**, try `Me.Controls("InputBoxValue").Text = ""`...

Comment: when i double click the userform "clear" button, it focus on the clear subroutine

Comment: Me.Controls("InputBoxValue").Text = "" works. Thank you!

Comment: You should change the code to `Me.InputBoxValue.Text = ""`. Doing so, you will get a compiler-error when you misspell a control name. With you variant, you will get a runtime error.